Proguard is not working in NativeScript Android App is crashing
Proguard is not working in NativeScript. I am using 6.5.3 version of NativeScript and Implement proguard.
Whenever I doing minifyEnabled true ...
release build is generating successfully but crashing when open the app.
In platforms/android/app/build.gradle
and file added in android/app/proguard-rule.pro


minifyEnabled true             
shrinkResources true             
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'



